# DESC command and key column within it

Tags: mysql, sql

I have created a table in my database and added a few constraints. When i use the `DESC` keyword on my table, depending on what constraints I placed, the Key column changes its record.

Here's the table definition:

```
CREATE TABLE t(
 sif  INT,
 sif2 INT NOT NULL,
 sif3 INT          UNIQUE,
 sif4 INT NOT NULL UNIQUE
);
```

and Here's the `DESC` result:

```
    mysql> desc t;
    +-------+---------+------+-----+---------+-------+
    | Field | Type    | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
    +-------+---------+------+-----+---------+-------+
    | sif   | int(11) | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
    | sif2  | int(11) | NO   |     | NULL    |       |
    | sif3  | int(11) | YES  | UNI | NULL    |       |
    | sif4  | int(11) | NO   | PRI | NULL    |       |
    +-------+---------+------+-----+---------+-------+
    4 rows in set (0.01 sec)
```

Why did my column sif4 get the key value PRI? I never mentioned a primary key definition and yet the `DESC` keyword shows that the column is set up as a primary key.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`DESC t` or `DESCRIBE t` is equivalent to `SHOW COLUMNS FROM t`. In the output from the `SHOW COLUMNS` command, a unique index may be displayed as `PRI` if it cannot contain null values and there's no primary key in the table.

In your case, the `sif4` column qualifies, as it's declared as

```
sif4 INT NOT NULL UNIQUE
```

From the [documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/show-columns.html):

> A UNIQUE index may be displayed as PRI if it cannot contain NULL
>   values and there is no PRIMARY KEY in the table. A UNIQUE index may
>   display as MUL if several columns form a composite UNIQUE index;
>   although the combination of the columns is unique, each column can
>   still hold multiple occurrences of a given value.