# KEY and PRIMARY KEY in CREATE TABLE()

Tags: mysql, sql, indexing, primary-key, create-table

Trying to understand the peculiarities of the keys. The documentation says that KEY = INDEX, and PRIMARY KEY - a different type of key. This is OK. 
But there is the code:

```
$db = mysqli_connect ('localhost', 'root',''); 
mysqli_query ($db, 'CREATE DATABASE IF NOT EXISTS publications;'); 
mysqli_query ($db, 'USE publications;'); 
// try to create a field with the usual non-unique index that is not a primary key: 
mysqli_query ($db, 'CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS classics1 (author INT KEY)'); 
// output the indexes on the table: 
$res = mysqli_query ($db, 'SHOW INDEX IN classics1');
```

Why the author field contains a **primary key**? I did not write something in the request (the apparent creation of a primary key) like this:

```
$res = mysqli_query ($db, 'CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS classics1 (author INT PRIMARY KEY)');
```

By the way, if you add a row to the query:

```
mysqli_query ($db, 'ALTER TABLE classics1 ADD KEY (author)');
```

... then add a normal index. Why in the CREATE TABLE () KEY becomes PRIMARY KEY?

Comment: Have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24593894/desc-command-and-key-column-within-it/24593927#24593927

Comment: Thanks, understand, but my field author is not unique and can have NULL-values. So I don't undestand, have field author PRIMARY KEY or not and why?

Comment: @Boolean_Type : A "Key" means "a unique identifier for the row". A "Primary Key" is the main unique identifier and the one is use (at least most often) to link to other tables via Foreign Keys. If you have a field that is not unique that will be filtered on, then you create an Index. Here it sounds like a) the first Key defined is assumed to be the Primary Key, and b) the author field is not really a Key.